# Let $S$ be a set .What is $|S|$, if $|\{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\} |=29$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Let $S$ be a set .What is $|S|$, if $|\{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\} |=29$?

I Basically have no idea how to even approach this question. Any hints or explanations will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if $S$ has $n$ elements...how many subsets of order $0$ are there?  how many of order $1$?  How many of order $2$?

Comment: Let me try to guess and check. Let's see, a $4$-element set has $11$ subsets of size $\le2$, a $5$-element set has $16$, a $6$-element set has $22$, a $7$ element set has $29$, an $8$-element set has $37$, so the answer is $7$. No idea how to even approach this question? I am curious, what stopped you from doing what I did?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of subsets of size $k$ from an $n$ element set.

You have then $|\{x\in \mathcal{P}(S)~:~|x|\leq 2\}|=|\{x\in \mathcal{P}(S)~:~|x|= 0\}|+|\{x\in \mathcal{P}(S)~:~|x|= 1\}|+|\{x\in \mathcal{P}(S)~:~|x|= 2\}|$

and so letting $|S|=n$ you have

$|\{x\in \mathcal{P}(S)~:~|x|\leq 2\}| = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}$

From here, you should be able to solve for $n$ using algebraic techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Lets call $|S|=N$.

There are $\binom{N}{2}$ subsets of $S$ with two elements,  $\binom{N}{1}$  with one element and $\binom{N}{0}$ with zero elements.

Therefore, $\binom{N}{2} + \binom{N}{1} + \binom{N}{0} = 29$  or equivatenly ,

\begin{align*}
0&=\frac{N(N-1)}{2} + N -28 \\
&= N^2 +N -56
\end{align*}

The solution for that is either $N=7$ or $N=-8$.

Because we are looking for a positive number, $|S|$ must be $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Think it out.

First let's rule out that $S$ can't be infinite.

If $S$ is infinite than for every $s\in S$ there is the  set $\{s\}$ and there are an infinite number of such sets.  And $\{s\} \subset S$ and $|\{s\}| = 1\le 2$ and so $\{s\}\in \{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\}$ and $|\{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\}|$ is infinite.

But $|\{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\}|=29$, so $S$ is finite.

Now lets Suppose $S=n$.

If $x \subset S$ and $|x| \le 2$, then either

i) $|x| = 0$ and $x=\emptyset$.  There is only one set where this is true; the emptyset.

or

ii)   Or $|x| = 1$ and $x = \{s\}$ where $s\in S$.  The number of sets where this can happen is $|S|=n$.

or

iii) $|x| = 2$ and $x =\{s_1, s_2\}$ where $s_1,s_2\in S$.  If $|S|=n$ is finite, then there are $n$ choices that $s_1$ can be and $n-1$ chooses that $s_2$ could be.  But order doesn't matter so there are $\frac {n(n-1)}2 = {n\choose 2}$ (which is *literally* the number of ways to *choose* two elements for $S$).

So $|\{x\in\mathcal{P}(S):|x|≤2\}| = 1 + n +\frac {n(n-1)}2 =29$.

So $1 + n + \frac {n(n-1)}2 = \frac {2+2n + n(n-1)}2 = \frac {2+n+n^2}2 = 29$.

So $n^2 + n + 2 =58$ and $n^2 + n -56 = 0$ and so

$n = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4*56}}2 =\frac {-1\pm \sqrt{225}}2= \frac {-1\pm 15}2$ but as $n$ is non negative $n = \frac {-1+15}2 = 7$.

.....

If you really want to grok this let:

$S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

Then $x\in \mathscr P(S)$ so that $|x| = 0$ is $x =\emptyset\$.

And $x\in \mathscr P(S)$ so that $|x| =1$ are $x = \{1\}$ or $x=\{2\}$ or $\{3\}$ or $\{4\}$ or $\{5\}$ or $\{6\}$ or $x=\{7\}$.  There are seven such sets.

ANd $x \in \mathscr P(S)$ so that $|x| =2$ are $x=$ one of the following:  $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{1,5\}, \{1,6\},\{1,7\}$ or $\{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{2,5\}, \{2,6\}, \{2,7\}$ or .....,$\{5,6\}, \{5,7\}, \{6,7\}$.  There are $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$ of them.

If you count them up.... there are $29$ of them.